# Generalize WienerProcess

Tags: random-process

Together the **WhiteNoiseProcess**, which includes the option of specifying a specific distribution for the noise, and the **TransformProcess**, which allows functions of processes, provide a great deal of flexibility in creating discrete-time processes.

There does not appear to be a similar approach to creating a custom continuous-time process. For instance, it would be nice it the **WienerProcess** function included an option to specify a distribution other than the Gaussian.

I see from other questions that the discrete-time processes can be converted into continuous time processes by using Interpolation; however, it's not clear to me how to do this conversion in a way that the resulting process can be use with **RandomFunction**.  To be more specific, while a Interpolation can be used to specify a specific conversion given {t_min, t_max, dt} it's not clear how to define a general continuous time process that **RandomFunction** will recognize.

Comment: You can do `Accumulate[RandomVariate[yourdistribution,numsamples]]` but a Wiener-like process with a non-normal finite-variance errors is redundant. There is some discussion in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89092/non-normal-random-walks) but surely all random walks of finite variance error term ultimately converge to the WienerProcess in the limit because of the CLT? `ListPlot[Accumulate@RandomVariate[LaplaceDistribution[0,1],10^5]]` is practically indistinguishable from `ListPlot[Accumulate@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[2]], 10^5]]`

Comment: ^ in other words - if your process had a finite-variance non-gaussian underlying errors, then in continuous time it would be indistinguishable from the WienerProcess. If the errors were from a fat-tailed distribution like Cauchy, then it wouldn't exist in continuous time at all because it would blow up to infinity on any arbitrarily small time window.

Comment: @flinty Thanks for the suggestions.  Indeed my interest is in modeling fat-tailed distributions, but you bring up an interesting point regarding whether a process with infinity variance can be properly defined. This is what I'd like to explore further.  I understand the weight of the process will extend to infinity, but I'm not as sure that a formal definition is impossible.

Comment: There are families of stable-stochastic-processes from stable distributions even with infinite variance. For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_process but in this case they're not like the usual processes, and I don't think they're continuous like the Wiener Process (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy_process) . In the case of the Cauchy Process, the time is subordinated too. The number of time steps between jumps is itself random from a Lévy process. It appears Mathematica has no way to model this at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, this is also helpful